# Regular Expression to Match Non-Whitespace Characters

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I need to make a regular expression that matches something like:

```
JG2144-141/hello
```

or

```
!
```

but not:

```
laptop bag
```

or a string consisting of whitespace chars only (`' '`).

Right now I have `[A-Za-z0-9-!/\S]`, but it isn't working because it still matches with laptop and bag individually. It shouldn't match laptop bag and the empty string at all.

Answer (score 14):

**In general, to match any non-whitespace char**, you can use

```
\S              # Common modern regex flavors
[^[:space:]]    # POSIX compliant
[[:^space:]]    # POSIX extension (available in some flavors)
%S              # Lua patterns
```

The `\S` in `[A-Za-z0-9-!/\S]` makes this character class equal to `\S`, but you want to make sure all chars in the string are non-whitespace chars. That is why you should wrap the pattern with `^` and `$` anchors and add a `+` quantifier after `\S` to match 1 or more occurrences of this subpattern.

You may use

```
^\S+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c38XMQ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you. What would I do if I wanted to allow a space at the beginning of the word? For example:

"""
JG2144-141/hello !
"""

Comment: @JenniferHall: If you mean you want to match leading/trailing 0+ whitespaces, `^\s*\S+\s*$`. Or to match any non-word chars: `^\W*\S+\W*$` or `^\s*\S+\W*$`

Comment: No I meant it should match even if there is a space before. Like if you put the words in a triple quote """ and have JG2144-141/hello on the next line after the """, it won't match unless it is on the same line as the """.

Comment: @JenniferHall Please formulate the rules as your examples are not helpful enough to deduce those rules.

Comment: @JenniferHall Sorry, that does not make sense. Are you trying to parse Python code?

Comment: Sort of, I was given these words and told to match one or more non-whitespace characters

Comment: @JenniferHall Again, please formulate the rules. `JG2144-141/hello ! hi there` should not match as per the original post.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the original post, the words are meant to be put together like you just said. And only JG2144-141/hello and ! are supposed to match. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: @JenniferHall No idea what you are doing. [`(?sm)^"""(.*?)"""$`](https://regex101.com/r/c38XMQ/4)?

Comment: @JenniferHall Did that finally work for you?