# Python regex to get the closest match without duplicated content

Tags: python, regex, string, url, extract

**What I need**

I have a list of img src link. Here is an example:

- `https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/photo_2020-12-27_12-18-00-2-333x444.jpg&nocache=1`
- `https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/IMG_4945-333x444.jpeg&nocache=1`
- `https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/tri-shokolada.png&nocache=1`

I need get the following result:

```
studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/photo_2020-12-27_12-18-00-2-333x444.jpg

studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/IMG_4945-333x444.jpeg

studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/tri-shokolada.png
```

**Problem**

I use the following regex:

```
studiocake\.kiev\.ua.*(jpeg|png|jpg)
```

But it doesn't work the way I need. Instead of the result I need, I get link like:

```
studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/photo_2020-12-27_12-18-00-2-333x444.jpg
```

**Question**

How can I get the result I need with Python regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let a [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) [`.*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666768/how-dot-star-works) *consume* the starting match and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) the latter.

```
import re

matches = re.findall(r"(?i).*\b(studiocake\.kiev\.ua\S*\b(?:jpeg|png|jpg))\b", s)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WArSNC/3) (matches in *group 1*) or a [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##xZHBToQwEIbvPAXhYMBsCxSMugnhaDx48tqEFKjbCttO2sHVZN8dizFxj550DpNJJvP9/8zAByprqnXVR7AOYyejyMdNnCYKEfw@zz0uo7aDmCSdtHyji8hPQAZrUBrMT7KHgYDwHpVbKChovRua3w0vMFsx@hyURduxghWkZITddiGXd6QoCCNVVb3XdU1f4XBlAmlQsim54SaJ4i3@0ufj00NX39c3F6bk/7tCp4lXdrKzGAUFc@EoyaLoKDDU20@dpC/ajGKeU5ekrc7oNe/THxH@pcKDDH/eOu1@2@8ciOdw/SzjfbKLfUCC0wbTb3C2rp8)

---

Inside used `\S*` to match [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [characters other than a whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382087/regular-expression-to-match-non-whitespace-characters).
I further added some `\b` [word boundaries](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html) and the [`(?i)`-flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for *ignore case*.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to achieve, is a standard operation on URLs, and python has good number of libraries to achieve that. Instead of using regexes for this exercise, I would recommend using a url parsing library, which provides standard operations, and provides better code.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs


def extractSrc(strUrl):
  # Parse original URL using urllib
  parsed_url = urlparse(strUrl)

  # Find the value of query parameter img
  src_value = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)['src'][0]
  
  # Again, using same library, parse img url which we got above.
  img_parsed_url = urlparse(src_value)

  # Remove the scheme in the img URL and return result.
  scheme = "%s://" % img_parsed_url.scheme
  return img_parsed_url.geturl().replace(scheme, '', 1)



urls = '''https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/photo_2020-12-27_12-18-00-2-333x444.jpg&nocache=1
https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/IMG_4945-333x444.jpeg&nocache=1
https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/tri-shokolada.png&nocache=1'''

for u in urls.split('\n'):
  print(extractSrc(u))
```

Output:

```
studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/photo_2020-12-27_12-18-00-2-333x444.jpg
studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/IMG_4945-333x444.jpeg
studiocake.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/tri-shokolada.png
```

Answer (score 0):

My **hack** expression is this:

```
(https://)(studiocake\.kiev\.ua.*(php)\?src=https://)(studiocake\.kiev\.ua.*(jpeg|png|jpg))(&nocache=1)
```

To replace it with    `$4`

**Explanation...**

I just selected all the link **in parts** and then replaced it with the particular part needed.